# LDAP connection error while connecting the oracle database

Tags: oracle, ldap

URL : jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://ldapserver:389/cn=Manager,dc=test,dc=com

Status: Failure -Test failed: IO Error: JNDI Package failure javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'cn=Manager,dc=alation-test,dc=com'

when I search this using ldapsearch command, it returns results, but not able to connect to oracle

Please any inputs about this

```
**Search result below**

# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=test,dc=com> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# test.com
dn: dc=test,dc=com
dc: test
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain

# People, test.com
dn: ou=People,dc=test,dc=com
ou: People
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

# Group, test.com
dn: ou=Group,dc=test,dc=com
ou: Group
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

# clckwrk, People, test.com
dn: uid=clckwrk,ou=People,dc=test,dc=com
uid: clckwrk
cn: clckwrk
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword:: e2NyeXB0fSEh
shadowLastChange: 17400
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 1000
gidNumber: 1000
homeDirectory: /home/clckwrk

# adam, People, test.com
dn: uid=adam,ou=People,dc=test,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: adam
uid: adam
uidNumber: 16859
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/adam
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: adam
shadowLastChange: 0
shadowMax: 0
shadowWarning: 0
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9MUdoOTlGRUgwdEY2bXVlckliRnkxWmJzQTNhWEs5VGM=

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 6
# numEntries: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there's nothing in your LDAP results - as shown - with a Common Name (CN) of "Manager" as shown in your connect string, which explains the "No Such Object" return code.

Second, there doesn't appear to be anything in your LDAP to identify an Oracle Database. Oracle uses a very specific LDAP record format to identify TNS records - the same as you'd find in a tnsnames.ora file - within LDAP, and there's nothing shown here to indicate that you have that kind of data in your LDAP server.

Your connection string must identify a specific database service (hostname, port, service_name, etc.) as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/).

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@[[protocol:]//]host1[,host2,host3][:port1][,host4:port2] [/service_name][:server_mode][/instance_name][?connection properties]
```

You cannot use an LDAP lookup in the connect string to identify a user.

Comment: I followed this link to set up the LDAP server in the oracle database https://ittechsolutions2023.blogspot.com/2023/02/ldap-setup-with-oracle-database.html.
and I used this URL to connect oracle database,  jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://ldapserver:389/cn=Manager,dc=test,dc=com
please guide me on how we connect LDAP using oracle, its my DNS name.ora
LISTENER_TEST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxxxxxx)(PORT = 1521))
test = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxxxxxx)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = test)
    )
  )

Comment: The blog post you reference doesn't appear to make any sense. It sets up users in an LDAP directory but doesn't actually describe how it has *anything* to do with an Oracle database, other than what's mentioned in the title. It looks more like how you would set up LDAP to support SSH connections to the server *operating system*, not to the database itself, but it doesn't even describe *that* completely, as there are no steps to configure the server (DB or OS) to *use* LDAP for authentication. What version of Oracle database are you using?

Comment: Note: The LDAP schema used to store TNS (not DNS) information is proprietary and generally requires you to purchase one of Oracle's directory platforms rather than use OpenLDAP.

Comment: sorry its tns only, DNS is a typo.I am using the oracle 19.0.0 version

Comment: Do you have any reference Blogs or articles to set up an LDAP server in the oracle database?

Comment: My Goal is, I have oracle server 19c and I need to add an LDAP server in that 19c database, then I connect to oracle using LDAP authentication .

Comment: Oracle only supports LDAP authentication using their LDAP server, Oracle Internet Directory, or with Windows Active Directory if you're running Windows as the server OS. You can't use OpenLDAP for database authentication. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-19D6CA32-D7BC-4640-9BF3-93D169E7D7A4